# any_cast std::any pointer to specific pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, any

I would like `std::map<string, any> *var1` to point to the same memory address/value as `std::any *var2` because I know that `var2` is pointing to a `map<string, any>`.

The following seems to work:

```
std::map<string, any> *var1 = any_cast<std::map<string, any>>(var2);
```

Is it ok? The problem is that it does not signal bad cast even if `var2` is actually not an `std::map<string, any>*` but something else, but if it is it still works.

Am I doing it right?

```
std::map<string, any> *mapptr;
std::any realmap = std::map<string, any>({{"key", "value"}, {"key2", 5}});
std::any *ptrtomap = &realmap;
mapptr = any_cast<std::map<string, any>>(ptrtomap);
// Interesting part below
realmap = 6;
mapptr = any_cast<std::map<string, any>>(ptrtomap);
```

After changing the type of the variable to integer the any pointer is pointing to I can still cast that pointer to a pointer of type `std::map`.

What???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, any> *amap;
    any realmap = std::map<string, any>({{"key", "value"}, {"key2", 5}});
    any *ptrtomap = &realmap;
    amap = any_cast<map<string, any>>(ptrtomap);
    printf("Pointer real map: %x\n", amap);

    // Interesting part below
    realmap = 6;
    amap = any_cast<map<string, any>>(ptrtomap);
    printf("Pointer invalid map: %x\n", amap);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs e.g.

> Pointer real map: 11cfd00
>   Pointer invalid map: 0

So the illegal conversion returned a null pointer. The compiler can't detect invalid casts

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that it does not signal bad cast even if var2 is actually not an std::map* but something else

As reported in the [documentation of std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) (overload n.5):

> If operand is not a null pointer, and the typeid of the requested T matches that of the contents of operand, a pointer to the value contained by operand, otherwise a null pointer.

So actually you can check the cast's successful just checking the pointer.

```
mapptr = std::any_cast<std::map<string, any>>(&realmap);
if (!mapptr) {
  // invalid cast conversion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like `dynamic_cast`, `any_cast`ing a pointer returns the null pointer when it fails - it does not throw an exception.