# Casting specific pointer to std::any pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, any

You can use any_cast to turn an std::any* type into a pointer of the original type. But how do you do the reverse?

```
string h = “str”;
string *j = &h;
std::any *hh = reinterpret_cast<any*>(j);
cout << (*hh).type().name();
```

It will not work. Whichever type I use, if I dereference the resulting pointer and access a member with a “.” or I use “->” to access the same member on the pointer my application fails.

I tried static_cast and dynamic_cast too but that would not even compile.

Comment: `std::any_cast` does not work how you think it does.  See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) for what it actually does.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` - I don't care what you are casting from or to, it's *probably* a bug.

Comment: `std::any a = h; std::any *hh = &a;` is the way to do it. Not sure why you want to though, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @nathanoliver it works for the opposite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429709/any-cast-stdany-pointer-to-specific-pointer-type. If a variable std::any* points to a string, then you can use any_cast to convert it to string*

Comment: @AlanBirtles `std::any *hh = &h;` is a big no.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer There is no `std::any*` in that post.  There is a pointer to a map that contains an `std::any`.

Comment: @NathanOliver why? Yes when `h` goes out of scope `hh` will be dangling but thats no different to any other class. Depends what the OP is trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because you are not allowed to cast a pointer to an unrelated type.  a `std::any*` and a `std::string*` are not related.  That also is not how you are supposed to use `std::any`.

Comment: Ah, sorry I meant `std::any *hh = &a;`, @PatrikNusszer this is why we use proper variable names not single letters...

Comment: @AlanBirtles What's `a`?

Comment: `std::any a = h;`

Comment: @nathanoliver there are 2 code snippets in that post, the latter incolves any*

Comment: "You can use any_cast to turn an std::any* type into a pointer of the original type" - No you cannot (in all cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use a `std::any*`.  What you want is just a `std::any`.  To put something into a `std::any` you use

```
std::any anything_i_want;
//...
std::string some_string = "some text";
anything_i_want = some_string;
// now the any contains a `std::string`
std::string another_string  = std::any_cast<std::string>(anything_i_want);
// now we get the string out of the any
```

Comment: Do you know a generalised class, whose pointer version can be converted to the pointer of the specific type and vice versa? I would like a pointer that can point to any type and then I can cast it to that type of pointer which it actually is.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer `std::any`.  `std::any any_ptr = some_pointer; auto ptr = std::any_cast<type_of_some_pointer>(any_ptr)`

Comment: @PatrikNusszer I think the way you're talking about `std::any` is hiding what you're actually trying to do. Are you looking for a pointer that can point to any possible type? Are you looking for something like Java's `Object` which is the parent type of all classes?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer I recommend you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57437108/edit) your question to explain what made you want to do this, and what the bigger problem is that you're trying to solve

Comment: @nathanoliver you saved my day

Comment: @alterigel yes I would like something like java’s object though I know cpp does not have that

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking the following: if you have a pointer to an object that is known to be contained in some `std::any` object, how can you get a pointer to that `std::any` object?

In general, this cannot be done. In some cases, the object may be stored directly within the `std::any` object due to a small object optimization. If you are certain that this is the case, you could adjust the pointer yourself, based on the (very reasonable) assumption that an object of a given type is always stored at the same location within a `std::any` object, assuming that the small object optimization applies. For example:

```
std::any a = 42;
auto p = std::any_cast<int>(&a);
const auto offset = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&a);
if (offset >= sizeof(std::any)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("small object optimization doesn't apply");
}
// ...
// x points to an `int` inside a `std::any` object
auto q = reinterpret_cast<std::any*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(x) - offset);
```

(Unfortunately, there is no way to check at compile time whether the small object optimization applies to the particular type you care about.)

If the small object optimization isn't applicable, there is really no way to get back to the `any` object. It's sort of like asking, if you have a pointer to a node in a singly linked list, how to get a pointer to the previous node.

Comment: This is an example of an answer that only serves to make the problem more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string h = “str”;
std::string *j = &h;
std::any *hh =  std::any_cast<std::any*>(j);
```

Just to point out that it can be actually done. You can have a function receiving a pointer to a std::any for instance.